# Which word is appropriate for an on-line game website: appeal, accuse or complain?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, japanese

I'm translating an on-line game website into English, and the main idea of rules is that users can create a small game for other users. If the creator user provides answers that are not correct or not fair, the users with right answers want to click a bottom to tell the website administration, which word(s) should be displayed on that button?

1. appeal/appeal against
2. accuse
3. complain/complain about/complain of/complain against

[image]

Comment: Maybe "challenge".

Comment: 'Report' is the usual hedged term.

Comment: Agreed with Edwin. "Report" is what I see most commonly, online.

Comment: I'm also considering "Report", but I would like to keep it for another function that if a user creates something containing sexual or violent content, others can "Report". Is "Flag" also suitable for being used in this situation?

Comment: *contest* (verb)

Comment: If you wish to keep it separate from actual offensive content, maybe "Dispute"?